# what exactly is FlutterWindowMetricsEvent::pixel_ratio and how do you calculate it? (flutter_embedder.h)

Tags: flutter

Here is the definition of `FlutterWindowMetricsEvent` from the flutter embedder API:

```
typedef struct {
  /// The size of this struct. Must be sizeof(FlutterWindowMetricsEvent).
  size_t struct_size;
  /// Physical width of the window.
  size_t width;
  /// Physical height of the window.
  size_t height;
  /// Scale factor for the physical screen.
  double pixel_ratio;
  /// Horizontal physical location of the left side of the window on the screen.
  size_t left;
  /// Vertical physical location of the top of the window on the screen.
  size_t top;
  /// Top inset of window.
  double physical_view_inset_top;
  /// Right inset of window.
  double physical_view_inset_right;
  /// Bottom inset of window.
  double physical_view_inset_bottom;
  /// Left inset of window.
  double physical_view_inset_left;
} FlutterWindowMetricsEvent;
```

It is not clear from the docs nor from examining the flutter engine source code, what exactly `pixel_ratio` means.

So what exactly is `pixel_ratio`? how does one calculate it?